# How can I set the name of my loss operation in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In Tensorflow I can assign names to operations and tensors to retrieve them later. For example in one function I can do

```
input_layer=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape= [None,300], name='input_layer')
```

And then in another function later, I can do

```
input_layer=get_tensor_by_name('input_layer:0')
```

I came to believe that this is handy for making my tf code as modular as possible.

I would like to be able to do the same with my loss but how can I assign a custom name to that operation? The problem is that the build in loss functions (e.g., [tf.losses.mean_squared_error](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/mean_squared_error)) do not have a parameter for the name (in contrast to tf.placeholder, tf.variable and so on).

The way I refer to my loss at the moment is

```
tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES)[-1]
```

(retrieving the last loss operation that has been added to the graph). Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5):

I know that this is not exactly THE answer but it's a fix that could work for you.

Given that, as you pointed, the [tf.losses.mean_squared_error](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/squared_difference) function doesn't have a `name` parameter you could implement your own MSE (based on TF operations of course)

Just replace

```
tf_loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels,predictions)
```

With

```
custom_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(labels,predictions),name='loss')
```

And as `reduce_mean` does accept a `name` parameter you could get what you want.

Full example code available [here](https://github.com/alberduris/stackoverflow/blob/master/set_name_loss_operation_buechel/How%20can%20I%20set%20the%20name%20of%20my%20loss%20operation%20in%20Tensorflow.ipynb)

Answer (score 4):

I guess using a non trainable Variable should do the trick:

```
labels = np.random.normal(size=10)
predictions = np.random.normal(size=10)

sess = tf.Session()
loss_var = tf.Variable(10.0, name='mse_loss', trainable=False, dtype=tf.float32)

loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)
mse_loss = loss_var.assign(loss)

sess.run(mse_loss)
print(sess.run(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('mse_loss:0')))
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the shortest way to do this is by using `tf.identity`.

```
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)
loss = tf.identity(loss, name = "loss")
```