# Metric names for the GANs loss in Keras

Tags: python, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am working with the improved version of Wasserstein GANs, for generated images when given as input some features `X_{S}` coupled together with noise vector `z`. Furthermore, I would like to generate samples from specific classes. Therefore, a classifier was added to the standard training of the whole system. My code for building the whole system is the following:

```
class WGANGP():
def __init__(self):

    self.target_mod = ".."
    self.learning_param = 0.0001
    self.no_input_feats = ...

    # Following parameter and optimizer set as recommended in paper
    self.n_critic = 15
    optimizer = RMSprop(lr=self.learning_param)

    self.img_rows = ...
    self.img_cols = ...
    self.channels = 3
    self.img_shape = (self.img_rows, self.img_cols, self.channels)
    self.latent_dim = ...

    # Build the generator and critic
    self.generator = build_generator(self.latent_dim, self.channels)
    #self.generator = self.build_generator_old()
    self.critic = build_critic(self.img_shape)

    #-------------------------------
    # Construct Computational Graph
    #       for the Critic
    #-------------------------------

    # Freeze generator's layers while training critic
    self.generator.trainable = False

    # Image input (real sample)
    real_img = Input(shape=self.img_shape)

    # Noise input
    z_disc = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
    # Generate image based of noise (fake sample)
    fake_img = self.generator(z_disc)

    # Discriminator determines validity of the real and fake images
    fake, aux1 = self.critic(fake_img)
    valid, aux2 = self.critic(real_img)

    # Construct weighted average between real and fake images
    interpolated_img = RandomWeightedAverage()([real_img, fake_img])
    # Determine validity of weighted sample
    validity_interpolated, aux3 = self.critic(interpolated_img)

    # Use Python partial to provide loss function with additional
    # 'averaged_samples' argument
    partial_gp_loss = partial(self.gradient_penalty_loss,
                      averaged_samples=interpolated_img)

    partial_gp_loss.__name__ = 'gradient_penalty' 
    # Keras requires function names

    self.critic_model = Model(inputs=[real_img, z_disc],
                        outputs=[valid, fake, validity_interpolated, aux1])

    self.critic_model.compile(loss=[self.wasserstein_loss,
            self.wasserstein_loss,
            partial_gp_loss,
            'categorical_crossentropy'],
        optimizer=optimizer,
        metrics=['accuracy'],
        loss_weights=[1, 1, 5, 1])
    #-------------------------------
    # Construct Computational Graph
    #         for Generator
    #-------------------------------

    # For the generator we freeze the critic's layers
    self.critic.trainable = False
    self.generator.trainable = True

    # Sampled noise for input to generator
    z_gen = Input(shape=(self.latent_dim,))
    # Generate images based of noise
    img = self.generator(z_gen)
    # Discriminator determines validity
    valid = self.critic(img)
    # Defines generator model
    self.generator_model = Model(z_gen, valid)
    self.generator_model.compile(loss=self.wasserstein_loss, optimizer=optimizer)
```

When I am printing the `critic_model.metric_names` I am receiving the following:

> ['loss', 'model_2_loss', 'model_2_loss', 'model_2_loss', 'model_2_loss', 'model_2_acc', 'model_2_acc_1', 'model_2_acc_2', 'model_2_acc_3']

Can anyone help me understand what these names stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is right here:

```
self.critic_model = Model(inputs=[real_img, z_disc],
                        outputs=[valid, fake, validity_interpolated, aux1]) #<- 4 outputs

                                                              #4 model losses + 1 total loss:
self.critic_model.compile(loss=[self.wasserstein_loss,        #loss for output 0
                                self.wasserstein_loss,        #loss for output 1
                                partial_gp_loss,              #loss for output 2
                                'categorical_crossentropy']   #loss for output 3
                          optimizer=optimizer,
                          metrics=['accuracy'],           #replicated, one for each output
                          loss_weights=[1, 1, 5, 1])
```

Your model clearly has 4 outputs, and you defined one loss per output. Whenever you have multiple losses, Keras will sum a total loss for you, so:

- `'loss'` is the total loss (sum of all losses for this model)

The other 4 `'model_2_loss'` are, in order:

- `self.wasserstein_loss`, for the first output `valid`
- `self.wasserstein_loss`, for the second output `fake`
- `partial_gp_loss`, for `validity_interpolated`
- `'categorical_crossentropy'` for `aux1`

For the metrics, since you defined only one, the system replicated this same metric for each of the model's outputs:

- `'model_2_acc'`, metric for `valid`
- `'model_2_acc_1'`, metric for `fake`
- `'model_2_acc_2'`, metric for `validity_interpolated`
- `'model_2_acc_3'`, metric for `aux1`

---

For better loss names, you should add names to the outputs of the models, to the losses, etc., wherever it's possible to add a `name` parameter.

Some operations accept names, such as: [How can I set the name of my loss operation in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258166/how-can-i-set-the-name-of-my-loss-operation-in-tensorflow)

Losses in newer versions, created as objects, also accept names: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy

Models accept names, such as:

```
self.critic_model = Model(inputs=[real_img, z_disc],
                          outputs=[valid, fake, validity_interpolated, aux1], 
                          name='critic_model')
```

Layers accept names, so you should have a name for the output layer of each model to keep track of things better.

I'm not totally familiar with the new eager mode execution concept, but you might try to add a name also whenever you call a model... not sure whether this is possible.

Comment: Your answer seems complete and detailed. Therefore, I am going to accept it. However, I have a small question. Is there any good tutorial that explains the loss outcome. What if I have a big loss for the generator and small for the critic and the classification process? Is there a way to explain it? How can I explain the loss in case of Wasserstein GANs?

Comment: There might be many things involved. The most important ones are the activation, the range of the ground truth data, and whether the loss is "summing" or "taking a mean" of the pixels or distribution. I don't know a tutorial, but I'd go to the mathematical definition of the loss and see what it's doing. It might be necessary to divide by the number of pixels/units, or not. Since each loss has a different mathematical definition, it's normal for them to have different ranges.

Comment: Even though you don't want to dive deep in math, you can still judge your results and if they're bad you can roughly know which branch is not working well, and you could give a bigger weight to that specific loss.

Comment: Also looking at the losses and seeing if one of them is not evolving well. (It's normal for the discriminator to never get super good)

Comment: my issue is while I have a big loss for the Generator, the visual results are still very nice and very close to the distributions of the real one. Therefore, I am bit confused about the loss results if indeed make sense or not.

Comment: The hard part is to know what is considered low, and this depends from loss to loss. If the results are good, then I don't think you need to worry much.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to me that loss has not completely tractable behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You have two metrics the loss and the accuracy, keras generate the name of the metrics from layer where the outputs of your model are last defined.
The outputs of your model are outputs=[valid, fake, validity_interpolated, aux1] so you have four of them and all are define with the critic model:

```
 fake, aux1 = self.critic(fake_img)
 valid, aux2 = self.critic(real_img)
 validity_interpolated, aux3 = self.critic(interpolated_img)
```

so all are named name_of_the_model_name_of_the_loss -> Model_2_loss

This show how to add a name parameter to a layer to change the name given to the metric:
[Is there a way of renaming the metrics and losses of a Keras model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53504813/is-there-a-way-of-renaming-the-metrics-and-losses-of-a-keras-model)

edit on comment:

The source code from keras is here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L81-L2865

as shown in metrics_names function below, the first name is hard coded as 'loss' by default, probably because their is always at least a loss, and then name attribute is added automatically:

```
     @property
      def metrics_names(self):
        """Returns the model's display labels for all outputs."""

        # This property includes all output names including `loss` and per-output
        # losses for backward compatibility.
        metrics_names = ['loss']
        if self._is_compiled:
          # Add output loss metric names to the metric names list.
          if len(self._training_endpoints) > 1:
            metrics_names.extend([
                e.loss_name()
                for e in self._training_endpoints
                if not e.should_skip_target()
            ])

        # Add all metric names.
        metrics_names += [m.name for m in self.metrics]
        return metrics_names
```

The method return the self.name attribute of the losses and not a variable name that could be used with to call them

You can also use this simple code to see that metrics_names depend on last definition of models outputs:

```
input_ =  keras.layers.Input(shape=(8,))
x =  keras.layers.Dense(16)(input_)
output1 = keras.layers.Dense(32)(x)
output2 = keras.layers.Dense(32, name="output2")(x)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=input_, outputs=[output1, output2])
model.compile(loss=["mse", "mae"], optimizer="adam", metrics={"output2":"accuracy"})
print(model.metrics_names)

>>> ['loss', 'dense_3_loss', 'output2_loss', 'output2_acc']
```

Comment: I am a bit confused seems while it seems a repetition in the names, the results are different.  What is the first loss for example with name loss? Why for the acc case there are different numbers while for the loss the names are the same?

Comment: I think they are different object with the same attribute "name" that's why the method return identical names while the results are differents